# Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIImage' that accepts an argument list of type '(named: UIImage?)'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am getting the above error when trying to add this tuple to an array.

```
struct Cards{
    var cards: [(face: String, value: Int, image: UIImage?)] = []
}

var playerCards: [(face: String, value: Int, image: UIImage?)] = []

func dealCards() {
    self.createCards()
    var turn = 0
    for var i = 0; i <= self.cards.cards.count - 1; ++i {
        if turn == 0 {
            turn = 1
            self.playerCards.append((face: self.cards.cards[i].face, value: self.cards.cards[i].value, image: self.cards.cards[i].image))
        } 
        else {
            turn = 0
        }
    }
}

func createCards(){
    cards.cards.append(face: "Ace Of Spades", value: 14, image: UIImage(named: "ace_of_spades.png"))
}
```

Comment: That initialiser takes a string (the nAme of the image) not another UIImage

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to initialize `UIImage` object by `UIImage` object? Maybe this is correct?

```
func dealCards() {
    self.createCards()
    var turn = 0
    for var i = 0; i <= self.cards.cards.count - 1; ++i {
        if turn == 0 {
            turn = 1
            self.playerCards.append((face: self.cards.cards[i].face, value: self.cards.cards[i].value, image: self.cards.cards[i].image))
        } else {
            turn = 0
        }
    }
}
```

(I also fixed image index from `0` to `i`)

**Upd.** fixes in added code:

```
func createCards() {
    cards.cards.append((face: "Ace Of Spades", value: 14, image: UIImage(named: "ace_of_spades.png")))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I originally wrote, but am now met with error " 'Int' is not convertible to 'T' ". Any ideas?

Comment: @BiasWords_ corrected, try now. If will no work, provide all declarations to all variables with correct types that you used in your code.

Comment: Tried it out, now getting "Missing argument for parameter 'value' in call". Note sure why, even if i explicitly assign it a value it still provides the same error. Updated main post with code of all relevant areas

Comment: @BiasWords_ code that you just added also contain mistakes. Check my answer again